# Is this mail() function safe from header injection?

Tags: php, security, spam-prevention

I'm building a simple contact form for a website. It does not connect to a database, it just sends the email. Will this code prevent spammers from using header injections? Are there any vulnerabilities I'm not seeing?
<?php

```
//create short variable names
$name= filter_var($_POST['Name'],FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
$email= filter_var($_POST['Email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL);
$subject= filter_var($_POST['Subject'],FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
$message= filter_var($_POST['Message'],FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);

//set up some static information
$toaddress = 'blah@localhost.com,blahblah@localhost.com';

$mailcontent = "Customer name: ".$name."\n".
            "Customer email: ".$email."\n".
            "Subject: ".$subject."\n\n".
            $message;
            
$fromaddress = "From:" . $email;

//invoke mail() function to send mail
mail($toaddress, "Website Contact Form",$mailcontent, $fromaddress);
?>
```

Comment: Thanks everybody, all of the answers were helpful. I'm going with Alnitak's answer as long as nobody else can poke holes in it. Thanks Alnitak!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Header injection relies on being able to insert additional newlines into header variables, which makes the string look like a new header.

For example, allowing a subject value of `Testing\nCc: spamrecipient@example.com\n\nSome body text` would result in a message header containing:

```
Subject: Testing
Cc: spamrecipient@example.com

Some body text
```

i.e. the abuser has not only added additional recipients, but they've managed to supply their own body text too.

However in your case the `$toaddress` is constant, and even if `$toaddress` had been user-supplied it should be correctly sanitised by the `mail()` function.

Your subject header is similarly constant

The `$message` variable is safe because by definition that's the body text and only sent after the real headers.

That only leaves `$fromaddress`, and you're already using `FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL` on that which should also reject anything with a newline in it.

However you should strictly be checking the result of that test, and aborting the whole thing if the result is `FALSE`.  As it is if the validation fails then `mail()` will complain about being given a blank `From:` address, but there's no header injection opportunity there.

*As far as I can tell, then, this code is actually secure.*

---

Also, IMHO, you shouldn't send the emails from the user-supplied email address.  That would fall foul of anti-spam mechanisms such as SPF.

You should use a constant `From:` value belonging to your own domain.  If you like you could then use a correctly sanitised value in the `Reply-To` header to make it easier to have the subsequent reply go to the desired address.

Answer (score 1):

IMHO, your code is not secure, as you miss `\r` and `\n` characters. `filter_var()` only kills those, if `FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING` is used in conjunction with `FILTER_FLAG_STRIP_LOW`, which will also filter out any characters below ASCII 32:

```
$message= filter_var($_POST['Message'], 
                     FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING, FILTER_FLAG_STRIP_LOW);
```

Also, `FILTER_VALIDATE_MAIL` will return a true or false, which you also do not account for. I recommend to check out [this](http://www.phpro.org/tutorials/Filtering-Data-with-PHP.html) excellent source for `filter_var()`, as the main PHP manual is very short on information.

---

**Update:** As Alnitak pointed out, through the `\n\n` in the code, this actually doesn't matter.

Comment: none of the bare `FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING` variables are ending up in headers so there's no risk there.  Your point about checking the result of `FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL` is the same as I already made.

Comment: it's not even the `\n\n` - that's already in the message body, and isn't part of the headers.  It's only confusing because the OP is putting text in the body that _looks_ like headers (but aren't).

Answer (score -1):

Nope, that doesn't sanitize anything.

It would be very very easy to fudge up that mailer.

I can add anything in a post value (that you read) to manipulate the mailer.

Comment: And why? How? How to prevent it?

Comment: @Neal given he's using `filter_var`, I'm curious as to what additional vulnerabilities you can see.

Comment: @Alnitak the OP is just doing `FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING` in which I can pass any string into the post value that can screw up the mailer

Comment: @Neal - ah - so it doesn't remove newlines?

Comment: @Alnitak Why would it? New Lines can be a part of a string

Comment: Neal, can you provide an example (or, better, several different examples) of input that could cause mischief and what kind of code would deal with them?

Comment: @ikh the most crucial thing to prevent injection is to ensure that any field that will be put in the header cannot have any newlines inserted into it.  e.g. if you can force `value\nHeader: XXX` into the subject then you'll get an extra fake header.

Comment: @Alnitak As far as I can tell, the value that's going into the header is `$email`, which is checked with `FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL`, which (I think?) would reject strings with newline characters.  Am I wrong here? Everything else is going into the body.

Comment: @ikh I was just checking that, and I think you're right.  However correct usage would be to check that that call to `filter_var()` didn't return `FALSE`.

Comment: @Neal I think you're wrong - the OP is supplying constant values for all headers _except_ for `From:`, and that one _is_ being correctly sanitised using `FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL`.