# making form processing script more secure

Tags: php

what are some steps I can use to make this more secure?

```
<?php
foreach ($_POST as $field=>$value)
{
$formcontent .= "$field: $value\n";
}
$formcontent .= 'User-Agent: '.$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];


$recipient = "****.***y@***********.co.uk";
$subject = "Event feedback form";
$mailheader = "From: web.form@**********.co.uk\r\n";
$mailheader .= "Reply-To: $email\r\n";
$mailheader .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";


mail($recipient, $subject, $formcontent, $mailheader) or die("Failure!");
header("location:http://www.**********.co.uk");
?>
```

Comment: What do you mean by making this script secure? You are not storing data in database, so what "secure" means here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to apply [htmlentities](http://php.net/htmlentities) to $value to prevent cross site scripting.

```
$formcontent .= "$field: " . htmlentites($value) . "\n";
```

Otherwise, its okay, as your values don't go into DB.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the recommended answer here: [Is this mail() function safe from header injection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11040328/is-this-mail-function-safe-from-header-injection). Since you aren't storing in your database or using attachments, your risks are in the possibility of new lines in the header of the mail. If you follow those instruction there, you can filter out the new lines and you are okay.

Hope that helps!
Cheers

Answer (score 1):

Use [htmlspecialchars](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php) to sanitize the variables!