# Unable to create linebreak

Tags: php

I have been trying to create line break in the body of the message but its not working. All the text in the body is coming in one line.

```
<?php
if ($_POST["email"]<>'') {
    $ToEmail = 'demo@localhost.com';
    $EmailSubject = 'Site contact form';
    $header = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
    $header .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=iso-8859-1" . "\r\n";
    $header .= "From: ".$_POST["email"]."\r\n";
    $header .= "Reply-To: ".$_POST["email"]."\r\n";
    $message = "Name: ".$_POST["name"]."\r\n";
    $message .= "Email: ".$_POST["email"]."\r\n";
    $message .= "Comment: ".nl2br($_POST["comment"])."";
    mail($ToEmail, $EmailSubject, $message, $header) or die ("Failure");
?>
Your message was sent
<?php
    } else {
?> 
Sorry message was not sent
<?php
    };
?>
```

Comment: (a) what are sample POST values that you are having problems with?, (b) why are you needing to send HTML email?, (c) why are you not sending a multipart email with both text and HTML?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

\n wont work here

you are posting to an html page

you can use `<br />`

hope that help

Comment: where to change, only in $message ??

Comment: instead of \r\n everywhere you want a new line

Answer (score 1):

Change these lines:

```
$message = "Name: ".$_POST["name"]."\r\n";
$message .= "Email: ".$_POST["email"]."\r\n";
$message .= "Comment: ".nl2br($_POST["comment"])."";
```

To this:

```
$message = "Name: ".$_POST["name"]."<br />";
$message .= "Email: ".$_POST["email"]."<br />";
$message .= "Comment: ".nl2br($_POST["comment"])."";
```

You had the right idea with `nl2br`, but your message is also the "Name:" and "Email:" part - those lines need to be HTML lines as well, since you are sending an HTML email.

### Your code is vulnerable

As a side note, you should really be cleansing your input.  Just dumping `$_POST` values into an email is incredibly dangerous; it leaves you [EXTREMELY vulnerable to attacks](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11040786/761202).

Comment: [ it leaves you EXTREMELY vulnerable to attacks.] So what is a better way suggest please.

Comment: @AD7six: I can't find a good reference, or else I would add one... I guess I view it as just plain ol' good practice.

Comment: @aus_fas: The "better" way is to make sure they can't do anything nasty - for example, check `$_POST["email"]` to make sure it is a valid email address.  If a user posts "test@example.com\r\nCC: spam1@test.com,spam2@test.com,spam3@test.com" then those addresses will all be CC'd.  You need to ALWAYS check ALL user input for potential errors and hacks.  That's a whole 'nother question in and of itself if you don't know how to do it.  It's just good practice....

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `\r\n`  use  `<br />` becouse `\r\n` doesn't converts to html tag.

Comment: Tried  that  but not working either $message = "Name: ".$_POST["name"]."<br/>";
    $message .= "Email: ".$_POST["email"]."<br/>";

Comment: maybe you wrote `<br/>` instead of `<br />`