# Do I need to escape POST when sending emails?

Tags: escaping, php

I have the following code:

```
<?php

    $email_from = "oshirowanen@localhost.com";
    $email_to = $_POST["referred_email"];
    $email_subject = 'test subject here';
    $email_message = $_POST["referred_message"];

    // create email headers
    $headers = 'From: '. $email_from ."\r\n".
    'Reply-To: '. $email_from ."\r\n" .
    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

    if (filter_var($email_to, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
        $result = mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers); 
        echo 'Mail accepted for delivery ';
    } else {
        echo 'Mail could not be sent ';
    }

?>
```

Should any of the POST values be escape'ed in anyway to prevent malicious actions by users?  If yes, which escaping method should be used? magic quotes?

I'm using PHP 5.x.

Comment: Are you asking a yes or no question or a how-to question?

Comment: @Jazza, its an "if yes, then which method is appropriate for this question".

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is this mail() function safe from header injection?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11040328/is-this-mail-function-safe-from-header-injection)

Comment: One thing I can guarantee is that Magic Quotes is **not** the answer. You shouldn't be using Magic Quotes for *anything*. The Magic Quotes feature is deprecated, and has actually been removed entirely from recent PHP versions.

Comment: @Spudley, so which method should I use to escape the POST values?

Comment: I don't think the duplicate link is appropriate, as it uses a constant for the "to" email address.  My "to" email address is a variable determined by the user.

Comment: @oshirowanen - Well, I thought you wanted to understand what the problem is, rather that just getting the code reviewed. I suppose your precise snippet is fine.

Comment: @oshirowanen You edited your question body moments after I commented.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All output from your code should be escaped or sanitised in the appropriate way. That includes output that is sent as an email.

When it comes to writing email headers, you need to be extremely vigilant to protect yourself against injection attacks that could result in your mail being sent to arbitrary addresses, and with arbitrary content.

Ultimately this comes down to ensuring that your email addresses are valid and do not contain any line feed characters, etc, and your current `FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL` code is a good start at handling this.

However as it stands, your program basically allows a user to send any content they like to any recipient they like. They only hard-coded part is your 'from' address. This sounds like an open invitation for it to be used to send spam, regardless of any escaping you may be doing.

If this is your actual code, I advise you to reconsider what it's doing!

Once you've done that, I will advise you to download a copy of the [phpMailer class](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer), and use that for sending emails in PHP rather than the built-in `mail()` function. It's a lot easier to use, has a lot more functionality, and most importantly, it does all the validation, sanitisation and escaping for you, so you don't need to worry about it any more.

Hope that helps.

Comment: so phpMailer can't stop curl scripts and/or bots from spamming emails from the code?

Comment: @oshirowanen - Your original code takes input from the user and sends it to whatever address the user wants, without any limits on the content of the message or who it is sent to. If you do that, nothing can stop it from being used for spam. phpMailer will make it easier for you to prevent unauthorised spam in a more restricted system, but your system is so unrestricted that spam is inevitable.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, ALL of them need to be escaped or at least validated.

For example, your `email_to` could contain thousands of addresses - this may be ok for your use case, but I doubt it.

Also, the POST parameters are going into the mail headers, which is a dangerous operation because it can manipulate the mail server to do completely different things than expected.

Answer (score 0):

Escape anything you get from a user. It could be anything.

Answer (score 0):

First, most people confuse the meaning of the word "escaping".

They take it as a some sort of "make the data magically safe, no matter of the data nature or it's destination". Most of time it is considered in the form of adding some characters to other characters.

Of course, no such escaping ever exists.

In real, data have to be **formatted** or **validated** depends of the nature of it's destination. and whatever "escaping" could be only **part** of such a formatting, or even not used at all.

In this particular case data being added to **mail header** and **mail body**.

Headers are prone to main injection - thus, they have to be checked to contain no linefeeds.
You are right checking email to.
As long as you have the subject hardcoded, it obviously require no validation. However, in case you get it from the form, it have to be validated as well. Make sure there are no linefeeds in it.

Mail body considered safe as long as you are sending plain text messages.

So, your code looks safe at the moment.

However, the very idea of such a mail form with **open address**, can be used as a **spam gate** - as anyone, actually, can send email from your name to anyone.

Answer (score -1):

This will cause `Email Injection`. You should read following document:

http://www.phpsecure.info/v2/article/MailHeadersInject.en.php