# I want to send an email from an html form that shows a popup when the email is sent

Tags: php, email, popup

I should preface this post with the fact that I am just a hobbyist and am not real code savvy when it comes to PHP and JQuery and such.  What I am trying to do is send an email from an HTML form using a PHP script that I found on the internet somewhere.  I have this all working just fine, but I dont like the fact that after the email is sent, the user is sent to a new page with a message saying it was sent.  Instead of opening a new page, I would like the user to stay on the same page and get a popup message instead.  Here is the code I am using for my PHP script:

```
<?php
ini_set( 'display_errors', 1 );
error_reporting( E_ALL );
$name = $_POST['name'] ; 
$email = $_POST['email'] ;
$subject = "Mail from website";
$message = $_POST['message'] ;
$to = "johndoe@gmail.com";
$headers = "From:" . $email . "\r\n" .
           "Reply-To:" . $email;
if(mail($to,$subject,$message, $headers)) {
    echo "Your email was sucessfully sent!";
} else {
    echo "The email message was not sent.";
}
?>
```

I did not attach my html since I didnt think it was really needed.  Any help on this would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Look into javascript and ajax, that will allow you to send a request to the PHP page without changing pages.

Comment: Your email also is injectable as is. https://stackoverflow.com/a/11040786/3783243

Answer (score 0):

Redirect to a query string like `header("location: formfile?msg=success");`
And then in order to pull message just use `$parts = parse_url($url); parse_str($parts['query'], $query); $alert_value = $_GET['msg'];` in file where your form is located. After that you can do actions with if statements.

**Here is example:**

the file where form is located

```html
<?php 
$parts = parse_url($url);
parse_str($parts['query'], $query);
$alert_value = $_GET['msg'];

if ($alert_value == "success") {
//do your actions to show lighbox.
}


?>


<!-- Your code for form in html --->
```

And your file where you send email:

```html
<?php
ini_set( 'display_errors', 1 );
error_reporting( E_ALL );
$name = $_POST['name'] ; 
$email = $_POST['email'] ;
$subject = "Mail from website";
$message = $_POST['message'] ;
$to = "johndoe@gmail.com";
$headers = "From:" . $email . "\r\n" .
           "Reply-To:" . $email;
if(mail($to,$subject,$message, $headers)) {
    header("location: formfile.php?msg=success");
} else {
    header("location: formfile.php?msg=error");
}
?>
```

Comment: I gave this a try and was not able to get it to work correctly.  I ended up just redirecting to a new page with the message on it instead.  Thanks for the help though!

Comment: formFile.php is just example. Try to replace formFile.php to your original file name where you wrote form code.

Comment: oh ok!  yea, I guess I shouldve realized that.  that did the trick.  Thanks again!